# Any python library with caching decorators for non-hashable parameters?

Tags: python, caching, memoization

I need some library that allow for easy caching.
The problem is currently available solutions like caching decorators from `functools` require arguments of the function/method being cached to be hashable. 
Is there any python library with caching decorators for non-hashable parameters? (Which automatically uses arguments' `id` values if they don't implement `__hash__`, maybe?)